# Css animation with translate problem only on mobile

Tags: css, animation, translate

I have a problem with image animations only on mobile. On the desktop it works well and on the mobile when I enter the site for the first time, something wrong happens only the first time I enter. If I refresh the page, it works well on furniture. I mention that on the div below with texts it works ok but not on images.

```
.slide-in-left {
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-name: slide-in-left; 
}

.slide-in-right {
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-name: slide-in-right;
}

@keyframes slide-in-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-in-right {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

You can see in the gif below what is happening:
https://gifyu.com/image/SM16Q

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that your client-side is cached?

Comment: What exactly would your problem be? Animation in the picture is not smooth? If yes, it could probably be that the width size of the smartphone is too small in relation to the computer screen and there will be no space for the images to be animated.